# In Rails < 3, rake task to copy vendor plugin assets to public vendor assets folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, assets

I'm new to Rails. I have been doing some work on asset resources (e.g. javascripts) in a vendor plugin's assets directory and hate having to restart webrick every time I change a file to get it copied over to the appropriate location in the public assets folder.

e.g. from vendor/PLUGIN/assets to public/plugin_assets/PLUGIN

I'm trying to figure out what task the server script fires off to accomplish this so that I can add a shortcut task in my IDE. We are moving to Rails 3.1 at some point, but for now I need something quick and dirty that doesn't require changing the code base or introducing dependencies. Anybody know where this is done? I might end up debugging the damn thing to see where this happens or right a simple 'cp -r' type script. Surely there must be something easier though ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for in:

```
vendor/plugins/engines/lib/engines.rb
```

includes the method **Engines.mirror_files_from** in it. So I wrote a rake task:

```
require "vendor/plugins/engines/lib/engines.rb"

namespace :myspace do
  desc 'Mirror plugin assets with public assets folder'

  task :mirror_assets do
    plugin = "PLUGIN_NAME"
    Engines.mirror_files_from("vendor/plugins/#{plugin}/assets",
      "public/plugin_assets/#{plugin}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a generator inside the plugin.

[See the example from my gem](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/generators/gmaps4rails/install_generator.rb).